# Remove Records from Tables Selectively Based on Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Scenario:

- I need to write an SQL script which will remove all records from some or all tables in a database with around 100 tables.
- Some tables are 'data' tables, some are 'lookup' tables. There is nothing in their names to indicate which they are.
- Sometimes I will want the script to only remove records from the 'data' tables, on other occasions I will want to use it to remove data from all tables.
- The records have to be removed from the tables in a very specific order to prevent foreign key constraint violations.

My original idea was to create a variable at the start of the script - something like `@EmptyLookupTables` - which I could set to true or false, and then I could wrap the `DELETE` statements in an `IF...` statement so that they were only executed if the value of the variable was true.

However, due to the foreign key constraints I need to include the `GO` command after just about every `DELETE` statement, and variables are not persisted across these batches.

How can I write a script which deletes records from my tables in the correct order but skips over certain tables based on the value of a single variable? The database is in Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL. Something like IF @someVariable = 1 EXEC ('DELETE FROM table');

Comment: Organize a list of tables that you want to be truncated in correct order in terms of foreign keys. Then write a dynamic SQL to loop through the list by passing in the names of table in correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a #temp table and store your variable in it, it will persist across `GO` separated batches. Then just check the temp table inside every batch.

```
SELECT @EmptyLookupTables AS EmptyLookupTables INTO #tmp
GO
DECLARE @EmptyLookupTables BIT
SELECT @EmptyLookupTables = EmptyLookupTables FROM #tmp
DELETE FROM YourLookupTable WHERE @EmptyLookupTables = 1 
GO
```

or you can even join directly on #temp table in delete command

```
DELETE l FROM YourLookupTable  l
INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.EmptyLookupTables = 1
```

Comment: But if my script goes: `DELETE FROM LookupTable WHERE @EmptyLookupTables = 1 GO` then the variable won't be accessible by the next WHERE statement. The variable is not accessible after a GO command.

Comment: aha, I see, i thought you are looking to remove `GO`, i'll fix the answer

Comment: That's very neat, storing the variable value in a temporary table, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of doing this without writing a parser for DDL in TSQL is to turn it on its head.

Create a new database with the same schema; populate the lookup tables, but without the records you don't want. Then populate the data tables, but again leave out the records you don't want. Finally, rename or delete the old database, and rename the new database to the original name.

It's still hard, though.